# How do you get terminal to explain a command?

Tags: terminal, command, prompt

For example, I want to know what -r does in terminal. I can't easily find any documentation but I assume in terminal there must be way to have a command explained. I tried info [-r] and help -r, but these combinations haven't worked. I'm sure it is very simple. Thanks.

Comment: "In terminal" is meaningless. What operating system are you using? "-r" is not a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each command-line tool supports different options.
There is no standardization, even if a lot of commands implement the same arguments for the same actions (as -r).

So you need to get help on a specific command.

You can do it with the `man` command, to get the complete manual of the command:

```
man [COMMAND]
```

Like:

```
man ls
```

A lot of commands also implements the `--help` or `-h` arguments, for a shorter help dialog.

Comment: So I found at -r means recursive, but man -r didn't tell me that. It listed a bunch of unrelated stuff.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to get help on a **command**. You can't get help an an **alone argument**, as arguments are **specific** to commands.

Comment: Oh.. so there is no way to find what command an alone argument comes from? And are you saying even though -r was recursive in this scenario it will mean different things with different commands? That makes sense, thanks. So I should be looking up help for the command before the -r, in this case cp. So I did man cp and it came up with what I was looking for, thanks for the clarification and answer.